# Wireless won't work on Xubuntu 11.10, but worked with live CD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, internet, xubuntu

I just installed Xubuntu 11.10 on my system and wireless doesn't work. The wireless card worked perfectly on Ubuntu 11.10 and on the live CD version of Xubuntu 11.10. As soon as I installed Xubuntu 11.10 on my HDD, the wireless stopped working. I know it's not a driver issue, because it worked with everything else. The menu where you select the appropriate wireless network is grayed out and I can't even see available networks. If I unplug the wireless adapter and plug it back in, the light just stays solid. Any suggestions on things I can try?

Comment: Have you tried disabling and enabling wireless multiple times? I do this on 11.10 Mint. Maybe your card is somehow unstable.

Comment: I reinstalled again and everything worked fine. It seemed to happen, because I didn't select format when laying out custom partitions. One of Linux's many odd bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled again and everything worked fine. It seemed to happen because I didn't select the format option when creating the custom partitions.

Answer (score 1):

> I know it's not a driver issue, because it worked with everything else.

That is not enough justification for that deduction...

Try scanning `/var/log/dmesg` for the name of your wireless driver (e.g. iwlagn) or the name of your wireless device (e.g. wlan0) and look for error messages.